# how to print current value of a running uwsgi configuration options

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm not sure why this question was not asked before. But I want to check current value of a running uwsgi configuration options, such as socket-timeout or uwsgi_read_timeout. The reason being is that by checking the current values, I can confirm the values set in config files

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/etc/uwsgi.d/main.ini
```

actually take effect. this is to avoid the situation where typos in configuation file prevent the value being applied.

Can:

```
uwsgi --show-config
```

or,

```
uwsgi --get
```

be used for this purpose? if so, how to specify the uwsgi instance I want to check config values for? what is the complete syntax?